# Change the value of the columns in the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone

I have something like this:

```
<ListBox Margin="10, 10, 10, 1" Visibility="Visible" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Remind_list}" x:Name="Reminders_list" Background="Transparent" Height="auto">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="440">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/bg.png"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Images/check.png" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="{Binding Checked}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Tap="RemindName_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10,2,0,0" Foreground="White" Height="40"  Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="24" Width="365"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This is a binding listbox.

How to change the value of the column and the "Grid.Column" in the image and textblock in C#?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong and what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to swap the image with the textblock

Comment: Dynamically in code behind? For all items at once or there could be swapped and not-swapped items?

Comment: Yes, the code dynamically. For all at once. This will be done once and before the show even application.

Comment: Then simply create 2 views and make only one visible, depending on some `bool` bound property.

Comment: I thought so before, but for unknown reasons the 2 option does not display results when i change value "collapsed" to "Visible".

This invisible part looked something like this: `<ListBox Margin="10, 10, 10, 1" Visibility="Collapsed" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Remind_list}" x:Name="Reminders_list_left"...> ... <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ...> <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ..>`

Comment: Already did it :X all the time I forgot to add data to the second listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Create second view and switch between them. Here is switching example

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Visibility _visibility1;
    public Visibility Visibility1
    {
        get { return _visibility1; }
        set
        {
            _visibility1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Visibility _visibility2;
    public Visibility Visibility2
    {
        get { return _visibility2; }
        set
        {
            _visibility2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel() { Visibility1 = Visibility.Visible, Visibility2 = Visibility.Collapsed };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vm.Visibility1 = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _vm.Visibility2 = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vm.Visibility1 = Visibility.Visible;
        _vm.Visibility2 = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
    <TextBlock Text="ListBox1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility1}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="ListBox2" Visibility="{Binding Visibility2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

`TextBlock` are your two `ListBox`es. `CheckBox` (and some code behind) is to simulate changing of `VisibilityX` properties, which normally should occurs when processing some `CommandSwapColumns`.

It is possible to use converter to bind to just one `bool` property.